# CakePHP 3.x Transacction - Not Enough RAM

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am saving a lot of data (Model which has a lot of models nested with different types of association). I am getting this data from an external webservice and after Marshall it I am trying to save with a transaction:

```
$this->connection()->transactional(function () use ($entities) {
    foreach ($entities as $entity) {
        $this->save($entity);
    }
});
```

The probleam I am currently having is that my php process is running out of memory. My php.ini is configured with 128M.

Is it possible to reduce the load of the data saving the entities without using a transactional?

Thank you.

Comment: You're trying to flush an unknown number of records through a single transaction - that's not good for many reasons, one of them being running out of RAM. More sensible approach is flushing 10, 50 or 100 records within a single transaction. Basically: break it up in multiple transactions and send in batches of 10, 50, 100 (or experiment with the number to hit the sweetspot).

Comment: Hi @Mjh, how can I approach that from CakePHP 3.x view? Could you provide an example or a link to doc that could explain me how to split it? I will try saving without the transactional stuff too just in a normal.

Comment: Your `$entities` is an array of data. Loop through it, divide it in an array of  50 records and use the code you posted in the question.

Comment: Well technically is not an array of data, it is an object which contains more than data, like other objects belongs to another models. Furthermore it is not a 1-dimension object because of its relations with another models. So at this point something simple like "array_split()" is not possible, right?

Even that there is a thing in CakePHP called EagerLoading / LazyLoading which I think supposes that not all the data is available from a "parent model" (which is what I have). The rest of the models are loaded dinamically. So I am a bit stuck now with your idea of doing small transactions.

Comment: Well, your current code has this: `foreach ($entities as $entity) {`. That means you can iterate `$entities`. My suggestion is to iterate them, collect 50, invoke your code for handling transactions. I don't think you are stuck, it might be that I worded my idea in a wrong way :/

Answer (score 0):

even though you have looped:

```
foreach ($entities as $entity) {
        $this->save($entity);
}
```

$entity probably still contains a lot of information, hence filling up the memory issue. You may probably echo out or use var_dump and see if you can have $entity further break it apart and have a nested loop inside the current foreach.